# "No Battery is Detected" but battery works

Tags: laptop, hardware-failure, battery, power, power-management

**The Question:**

**How do I get my battery to be detected again?**

My system is dual boot Windows/Linux.

On Linux, for a while, the system claimed that the battery was always at 15%.  Now, it says there's no battery.  When I unplug from AC power, if I force the battery icon to display, it still seems to think it's on AC power.

On Windows, the system displays my battery with a red X and the tooltip says "No Battery is Detected".  Occasionally, it will swap to an empty or full battery in charging state for a moment, then go back to saying no battery is detected.

**The battery works**.  If I unplug from AC power, I can get a couple of hours of battery life out of it, I simply have no way of knowing how much.

The worst part is, for whatever reason, it won't start without being plugged in (I guess because it doesn't see the battery).  No lights, nothing, like it's dead.  Of course, if I plug in just long enough to get the light on the power button to turn on, I can immediately unplug just fine.

Because 2 OS-es are having the same problem, and it is having issues even before BIOS is running, I'm tagging this as hardware related, but I have no idea how to determine the specific cause.

*For background:*

MSI GS70 Laptop (it has an internal battery).

I have attempted the battery reset technique of unplugging the battery, draining residual power and plugging it back in.

Comment: What's the question.

Comment: question made more clear

Comment: Is it an after market battery or an OEM battery?

Comment: original battery.  The only hardware changes are hard drive replacements (SSDs)

Comment: do you have a multimeter? I'd like to know what your battery rates as.

Comment: I do, how do I use it on the battery?

Comment: Have you flashed/updated the BIOS? Since this sounds like a hardware level problem, re-flashing the BIOS may reset the charging system. Also, if there is an update it would be a good idea to use it as it may resolve this and other issues.

Comment: The same issue after one of last Windows 10 update. Have no idea why my secondary OS (Ubuntu) stops to detect battery as well.