# No Battery Detected but it works if i disconnect AC

Tags: windows-10, laptop, power-supply, battery

I'm having the exact problem described in this question: ["No Battery is Detected" but battery works](https://superuser.com/questions/869732/no-battery-is-detected-but-battery-works)

A few months ago my laptop (ASUS ROG G750JH, bought roughly 6 years ago, now running on Windows 10) started saying the battery was at ~80% and it wasn't getting charged further. If i used my laptop on battery power it got drained and when i charged it again it went back at 80% and then stopped charging

Few weeks ago it got down to 12% and there was no way to make it go further but still worked a few minutes on battery power

Then a few days ago the battery stopped being detected at all and on battery power it didn't work at all, laptop just shut down if I disconnected AC cable.

So I bought a battery from Amazon, I tried my best to find an original battery but wasn't able to (this laptop still has removable battery so it's easy to change), at least not in a easy and trustworthy way. The battery i bought had good reviews so i didn't think about it too much

Finally, i ended up in the same situation described in the question above. If the laptop is powered up and i disconnect the AC cable it works, but the battery is not detected by windows and I can't turn it on on battery power alone.
The battery LED does not turn on at all

I followed the instructions written in this post but it didn't work
https://www.tenforums.com/drivers-hardware/63401-no-battery-detected-error-asus-laptop.html

> 1. Disconnect the A/C power supply.
> 2. Shut down the computer.
> 3. Remove the battery
> 4. Connect the A/C power supply
> 5. Start the computer.
> 6. Under Battery... (here's the problem, Jeff--where is "battery?" I searched, and finally remembered it is under Control Panel, then
>      System, then Device Driver, then Battery)
> 7. Click on Battery (at the top), and then right click on all entries that say Microsoft ACPI Compliant Control Method Battery, and select
>      uninstall.
> 8. Shut the computer down.
> 9. Disconnect the A/C power supply.
> 10. Insert the battery.
> 11. Insert the A/C power supply.
> 12. Start the computer.
> 13. It should be fixed--thanks to Jeffrey Palermo! Visit his blog to read what others have experienced, and solutions for those with
>       Samsung computers, etc.

How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a faulty battery. I have a g750jh as well and i bought a battery as well. The new battery works fine on idle but as soon as it gets stressed with running cpu or gpu intensive apps, it shuts down the laptop then restarts and wakes up to a 1% battery left from 100%.

Finding working batteries these days from ebay is a gamle. Probably only OEM parts from the laptop manufacturing themselves provides a 100% working battery or parts.